# Get array in [[target]] from proxy

Tags: javascript, javascript-proxy

How can i get this number from `productCount.value` (screenshot)?

Trying `productCount.value.array`, but i will get again proxy - [[target]] - array

Edit 1:
If i use `productCount.value.array[0]` i will get error Invalid value used as weak map key

[image: 11]

Comment: Have you tried `productCount[0]`?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @shaedrich - The OP claims the screenshot is a log of `productCount.value`, not `productCount`.

Comment: Please post code, error messages, console output, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: **If** that output is really from logging `productCount.value`, and `productCount.value.array` doesn't work, then the proxy doesn't let you have access to `productCount.value.array`. You can't directly access the [[Target]] of a Proxy, that's part of the point of them. So although the target has an `array` property, the proxy doesn't have to grant you access to it.

Comment: Have you by chance overwritten the `Proxy`'s `get()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Trying productCount.value.array, but i will get again proxy - [[target]] - array

That's not necessarily a problem. **If** the proxies (apparently there are at least two involved) allow you to access that array and its element 0, and you got the screenshot you showed from `console.log(productCount.value)`, you can do so like this:

```
const elementZeroValue = productCount.value.array[0];
```

Basically, you pretend the proxy isn't there, since it's a facade on the target. (A facade that may well limit or modify what you see.)

But that's only **if** the proxies involved allow that access. You can't directly access the [[Target]] of a Proxy, that's part of the point of them.

Answer (score 1):

A [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) in JavaScript stores its values *internally* within `[[target]]` which, as a property, is *inaccessable*. However, you can use the proxy in the same manner as you would use that object (or in your case array) normally because—as long as you hasn't tampered with that mechanism by overwriting its `get()` method—takes care of that, so `productCount.value.array[0]` should suffice.

If you have overwritten the `Proxy`'s get method, we would need to know about it to provide the proper answer.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure, but I think it's `productCount.value.array[0]`, since the OP claims that `productCount.value` produced what they provided in the screenshot.

Comment: Ah, you are right.